# Grunt Ruby Mac Errors

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, osx-mavericks

Somehow, I mucked up the grunt/ruby configuration on my Mac (OS X 10.9). When attempting to run grunt, I am now getting the following errors:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `open': No such file or directory - repos (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `entries'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `generate_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:13:in `block in <class:Server>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1393:in `configure'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:13:in `<class:Server>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:2:in `<module:Grunt>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/bin/grunt:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/grunt:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/grunt:23:in `<main>'
```

Anybody have any ideas of what is wrong? I have installed the latest version of ruby in ~/.rbenv since Mac doesn't play nice with the newer releases. I had this running before, but did something wrong my .zshrc file, and really messed everything up trying to troubleshoot it using various gem, npm and brew commands. I am willing to uninstall and reinstall everything, if someone could walk me through the process.

Comment: You're going to need to help us more than that. We need to know what you did.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot offer any more details than this, for I honestly do not know what I did. I am hoping that someone else would recognize the error from their own experience. I will continue to dig deeper, and if I find a solution, I will let everyone know. Many thanks!

Comment: Just got this too, haha. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes and no; I never figured out where these errors were coming from, so I just uninstalled all my gem packages, reinstalled Ruby 2.0.0, and reinstalled all the gems. This apparently cleared up the problem, and my grunt packages are working fine now.

Comment: Okay, I'll try the same thing. mavericks and ruby is farked.